# Controlling multiple CV in pedals from a single expression pedal

Tags: effects-pedal

I have several pedals on my board which have settings that can be controlled with an expression pedal.

How can I send the CV single from the expression pedal to multiple pedals. Passively splitting the single with a 1/4" Female -> Dual Male Y cable doesn't work.

Comment: The Moog CP-251 might do it for you. The potential (no pun intended) problem you might be having is that each CV input might be supplying a voltage to work with passive pedals. A passive splitter can cause problems with those different voltages, but an isolated mult can work as long as you supply the initial voltage to the pedal. The CP-251 can do that. It also has an amp and attenuators so you can scale the voltage if the different inputs need different voltage ranges.

Comment: Cheers! 
Now I have another thing to buy ;)

Comment: @ToddWilcox could you put that as answer so it can be closed out?